# Thymeleaf expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this piece of code in a Thymeleaf page, where I want to get something like selectAuthorizedDriver1,selectAuthorizedDriver2,...

I've tried with

```
<tr th:each="item: ${devices}" >
    <select th:id="selectAuthorizedDriver${item.id}" >
```

and

```
<tr th:each="item: ${devices}" >
    <select id="selectAuthorizedDriver${item.id}" >
```

and also

```
<tr th:each="item: ${devices}" >
    <select th:id="selectAuthorizedDriver${id}(id=${item.id})" >
```

But either I got the error:

```
 Could not parse as expression: "selectAuthorizedDriver${item.id}"
```

or literally    `"selectAuthorizedDriver${item.id}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For expressions where you just need a string, you can just append them together.  In your examples:

```
<tr th:each="item: ${devices}" >
    <select th:id="${'selectAuthorizedDriver' + item.id}">
```

You can also accomplish this using [preprocessing](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing), but it's not needed in this case. (If you need to write a th:field expression, you'll have to do it this way).

```
<tr th:each="item: ${devices}" >
    <select th:id="${'selectAuthorizedDriver__${item.id}__'}">
```